# Filtering document ID using views?

Tags: javascript, cloudant

I am using cloudant database to store my values and I specify my
document ID to be string+date(ddmmyy) (e.g foo071117). Recently I
need to filter the documents to show documents in the last 7 days
(e.g foo311017 to foo061117) and I have used views to do this. This is my code:

```
function (doc) {
  var datearr = [];
  var today = new Date()
  for (var i =1; i<=7; i++){
    var datesfull = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - i);
    var dd = datesfull.getDate();
    if (dd<10){
       dd = '0'+dd;
    }
    var mm = datesfull.getMonth()+1;
    if (mm<10){
       mm ='0'+mm  
    }
    var yy = datesfull.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
    var dates = "foo" + dd + mm + yy;
    datearr.push(dates);
  }
  if((datearr.indexOf(doc._id.slice(0,-1))>=0) || (datearr.indexOf(doc._id)>=0)){
  emit(doc._id,doc);
  }
}
```

The slice is for when my json files gets too big and I have to split the file into multiple files (e.g foo0711170, foo0711171)

This code works at the beginning as after running, cloudant view only showed 7 documents which I wanted. However, as the days passes, the old files remains instead of having just 7 documents. Is Cloudant supposed to refresh to show 7 documents in the View as specified in my code or is this due to how the data is stored?

*I can't query data for the past 7 days using URL as I am using powerBI which limits my ability to write a code to specify which document ID to extract so I can only use views as a filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you supply a design document to Cloudant with an index definition, the view is built and stored on disk. You may then query the view at a later time to get its results.

In your design document your are getting the time of "now", which in this case is the time when indexing is performed - not the time that the query is performed. It therefore cannot be used to extract data "in the last 7 days" (of the query time).

One solution would be to change the way your document `_id` is built. If you used: `yyyymmdd+string`, then your documents would be stored in date order because Cloudant has a primary index on the `_id` field.

You could then query the database's primary index, starting with a key 7 days in the past e.g.:

```
/mydb/_all_docs?startkey=20171101&include_docs=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Helped to clear up things for me